# Problem cross referencing when using include tcommand to include multiple files

Tags: cross-referencing

I have been dealing with a Latex bug for the past 4 months that I have been unable to resolve. The issue is that a lot of my cross references come out as ?? when I  use `\include{filename}` from a master file to include multiple .tex files and avoid writing a monolithic .tex file.

I discovered that I can fix the problem by lifting the figures out of the (tributary) files being included via include{filename} and putting the figures in the body of the main .tex file. But, this is not an ideal solution! ?? usually appear for labels that appear in the last few files of my document.

I am including my preamble below and the general form of my document. I thought this was a revtex4.1 problem but it persists when I switch to regular latex document class. I use kile as my TEX compiler on a 64-bit machine operated by Ubuntu 11.10 (yes, I will upgrade to 12.04 soon). My linux kernel is 3.0.0-32.

Please HELP!! I am desperate

```
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{soul}   % for highlighting
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


\includeonly{file1,file2,...}
\begin{documnent}
\maketitle

\let\clearpage\relax

\include{file1}
\include{file2}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Comment out the `\includeonly` line in order to let LaTeX process *all* the files. This is necessary if you want to get correct cross references.

Comment: A separate, minor comment: don't load both the `color` and `xcolor` packages, and don't load both the `graphics` and `graphicx` packages.

Comment: `\let\clearpage\relax` is a rather dangerous command it can put latex into an infinite loop (and it stops the `\include` system working)

Answer (score 4):

The fact that you wrote `\let\clearpage\relax` makes me suspect that what you are trying to do is simply to structure your source into several hierarchical files rather than to use the "include" mechanism. To do that simply use `\input` instead of `\include` and you should be fine. The `\input` command can even be nested (`\inlcude` can't) and will unconditionally load your files.

Disabling `\clearpage`as you did is not only dangerous as David politely remarked, it is plain wrong and will not only break the "include" meachanism but also lead to other errors depending on the content of your document.

As for `\inlcude`: it can only be used for parts of a document that start and end a new page, e.g., a whole chapter and it is only there to conditionally process parts of the document while developing. You still need to run the document in total once in a while to ensure that all cross references get properly processed. But if you do not want the `\clearpage`issued by the "include" mechaism, then it is definitely the wrong tool to use.