# Reference label with included file and relaxed clearpage

Tags: cross-referencing, include

I am running into a rather weird error that apparently originates from the combination of `\include`, `\let\clearpage\relax` and a referenced label after a page break.

In this particular example, the label `mylabel` defined in the listing cannot be referenced anymore when the reference and the label are close enough to a page break.

The MWE consists of two files, the main-file and an included file.
I am using the `\let\clearpage\relax` command to [avoid page breaks after every `\include`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10066885/2225200).
The error does not occur if the file is `\input` instead of `\include`d.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book} % 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Enoding
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{forloop}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax

\include{includedfile} % changing include for input would work

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Included file:

```
\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 40}%
{%
    .\\
}

Listing \ref{mylabel}.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=somecaption, label=mylabel]
some code;
\end{lstlisting}
```

Running this example will have an output where the label cannot be referenced (even after multiple runs):

[image: output example]

Now, one solution is to use `\input` as mentioned earlier but I am rather interested in why this happens.
Does the `\clearpage` command fulfil an important function for references to work?
And can the error be avoided without removing `\let\clearpage\relax` while using `\include`?

EDIT: I just found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103745/problem-cross-referencing-when-using-include-tcommand-to-include-multiple-files) with the same issue (though it does not have a definite answer).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\include` uses a separate `.aux` file. If the file is not included, the `.aux` file is still read and the references of the `.aux` file are available.

Entries into the `.aux` file can be written `\immediate` or at the time, when the page is shipped out. Therefore `\include` starts a new page. Thus the labels of the previous page goes into the previous `.aux` file. Then the `.aux` files are switched immediately (`\immediate\openout`). The labels go into the `.aux` file of the included file. After the included file is processed, `\include` calls `\clearpage` to output any stuff of the included file including labels, which goes into the `.aux` file of `\include`. Then again the `.aux` files are switched, the include `.aux` file is immediately closed and the next writes to an `.aux` file is going to the main `.aux` file.

With `\let\clearpage\relax` you destroy the capabilities of `\include`. In the case of the question, the last page of the included file contains the label. The shipped out page contains the command to write the label to file `includedfile.aux`. But the page is not yet shipped out before the end of `\include` and the file handle for `includedfile.aux` is *closed*. TeX then redirects the write request to a closed file handle at the next page shipout to the `.log` file, where you will find:

```
\newlabel{mylabel}{{1}{2}}
\@writefile{lol}{\contentsline {lstlisting}{\numberline {1}somecaption}{2}}
```

Also the entry into the list of listings will be missing.

## Summary:

[image: flash bold red]

---

As addendum the code for the "flashy thing" as requested by kan:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\doit}[2][]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    \color{#2}%
  \else
    \color[{#1}]{#2}%
  \fi
  \noindent
  \Large
  \sffamily
  \bfseries
  Never disable page breaks with %
  \texttt{\textbackslash include}!\\
  Use \texttt{\textbackslash input} instead.
  \newpage
}
\newcommand*{\x}[1]{%
  \doit[Hsb]{0,1,1}%
  \doit[Hsb]{#1,1,1}%
}
\x{30}
\x{60}
\x{90}
\x{120}
\x{150}
\x{180}
\x{210}
\x{240}
\x{270}
\x{300}
\x{330}
\end{document}
```

Then

```bash
pdflatex test
pdfcrop test.pdf
gs -sDEVICE=png256 -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dUseFastColor=true -r216x216 -sOutputFile=test%d.png -ftest-crop.pdf
convert -delay 30 -loop 0 test1.png test2.png test3.png test4.png test5.png test6.png test7.png test8.png test9.png test10.png test11.png test12.png test13.png test14.png test15.png test16.png test17.png test18.png test19.png test20.png test21.png test22.png test.gif
```

Comment: +1 but could you make the last line a bit bigger and bolder, and perhaps flash in red:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is it big, red, flashy enough?

Comment: A masterpiece of typographic design!

Comment: I'm in the middle of a seizure! `:)`

Comment: @Heiko: Code for the flashy thing? Of course, I don't want it except for nefarious reasons... :-)

Comment: @kan: I have added the code, but with the hope, the "flashy thing" remains an exception and does not start to enrich each answer or question.

Comment: Thank you! I promise I won't post on this forum or elsewhere, the flashy thing. I just want to look at how it's done.