# One subchapter does not appear in table fo contents

Tags: table-of-contents

In my `.pdf` output document the last of my subchapters does not appear in the table of contents.
All the chapters are in different `.tex` files, which are included into a main file.

All of them are correctly listed in the table of contents, just not the last one.

It is listed in the contents which I can navigate to using Adobe Acrobat.

Here is what the build output says:

As you can see it shows additional output for the subchapter 2.4.2 which is not listed in the table of contents. For every other chapter there is no such output.

```
pdflatex.exe> (C:\ST\Papers/atl.tex [9])
pdflatex.exe> (C:\ST\Papers/comm.tex
pdflatex.exe> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ae\omsaer.fd") [10])
pdflatex.exe> (C:\ST\Papers/sparx.tex) [11
pdflatex.exe> \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.4.2}Sparx Systems En
pdflatex.exe> terprise Architect}{11}{subsection.2.4.2}}
pdflatex.exe> \newlabel{ch:RelatedWork:sec:Commercial:subsec:EA}{{2.4.2}{11}{Sparx Systems En
pdflatex.exe> terprise Architect}{subsection.2.4.2}{}}
pdflatex.exe> ] (C:\ST\conclusion.tex
```

I already googled for the `\@writefile{toc}` line, but could not find any help online so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm trying to abstract my project, but it's provided by my university and therefore very huge. But I found out it seems to be related to the command I put around the include commands: \begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax .. I used this to prevent Latex to put every section on a new page. If I don't use it then the last subcsection is also shown in the table of contents

Comment: It looks that you are using `\include`, but have disabled `\clearpage`. Then it is a duplicate: [Reference label with included file and relaxed clearpage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185233/16967)

Comment: @Heiko, that seems helpful at first glance. will investigate later. thx

Comment: @PogoMips Don't use `\include`, it's that easy; change all of them into `\input` and live happy. No need of `\begingroup\let\clearpage\relax`, of course.

Comment: Voted to close this as the duplicate @HeikoOberdiek linked to. The warning is so appealing to the human eye. Attention: Can cause epileptic attacks.