# Is newclude (still) a good package to use?

Tags: compiling, include

I came up with this very MWE while trying to organize my code into several section files to speed up compilation of a journal paper (`section`s, not `chapter`s!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{newclude}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-ext.tex}
    \section{A section}
    \label{sec:A}
    References to this section \ref{sec:A} do not work.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \include{\jobname-ext}
    \endgroup

    \section{Another section}
    No page break after section \ref{sec:A}, please!
\end{document}
```

Surprisingly (at first), the result lacks correct references. It is less surprising seeing [Problem cross referencing when using include tcommand to include multiple files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103745/problem-cross-referencing-when-using-include-tcommand-to-include-multiple-files) and [Reference label with included file and relaxed clearpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185233/reference-label-with-included-file-and-relaxed-clearpage), in particular, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185237/30810).

Now, looking at those question above as well as [Reactivating “\clearpage” in LaTeX after turning it off with “\let\clearpage\relax”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176107/reactivating-clearpage-in-latex-after-turning-it-off-with-let-clearpage-rel), not a single answer or comment (or question) mentions the `newclude` package, which offers an `\include*` command that does not issue a `\clearpage`. I wonder if this is an OK package to use, since it has not been updated [since 1999](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/frankenstein/newclude.pdf).

Here's another piece of code that works without redefining `\clearpage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{newclude}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-ext.tex}
    \section{A section}
    \label{sec:A}
    References to this section \ref{sec:A} DO work.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \include*{\jobname-ext}

    \section{Another section}
    No page break after section \ref{sec:A}, please!
\end{document}
```

And here are two more that don't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\include#1{\relax
  \ifnum\@auxout=\@partaux
    \@latex@error{\string\include\space cannot be nested}\@eha
  \else \@include#1 \fi}
\def\@include#1 {%
  %\clearpage
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{#1.aux}}%
  \fi
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \let\@auxout\@partaux
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\openout\@partaux #1.aux
      \immediate\write\@partaux{\relax}%
    \fi
    \@input@{#1.tex}%
    %\clearpage
    \@writeckpt{#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\closeout\@partaux
    \fi
  \else
    \deadcycles\z@
    \@nameuse{cp@#1}%
  \fi
  \let\@auxout\@mainaux}
\makeatother
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-ext.tex}
    \section{A section}
    \label{sec:A}
    References to this section \ref{sec:A} do not work.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \include{\jobname-ext}

    \section{Another section}
    No page break after section \ref{sec:A}, please!
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@include}{\clearpage}{}{}{error}
\patchcmd{\@include}{\clearpage}{}{}{error}
\makeatother
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-ext.tex}
    \section{A section}
    \label{sec:A}
    References to this section \ref{sec:A} do not work.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \include{\jobname-ext}

    \section{Another section}
    No page break after section \ref{sec:A}, please!
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `newclude` has ever worked as intended.

Comment: where does this `\let\clearpage\relax\include{...` idiom come from?  It keeps coming up, but it is completely broken. If there is  a tutorial that recommends this it should be fixed.

Comment: @egreg do you have an example that fails? I have included `newclude` in my 25-page `iopart` document with figures, tables, lists of figures/tables, appendices and a bibliography, and I don't note any difference to the previous compilation output.

Comment: @bers You're being lucky, I believe.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why not just use `\input` instead of `\include` if you don't want a `\clearpage`?

Comment: @IanThompson because I like to use `\includeonly`.

Comment: If `newclude` is not recommended (and you should probably take egreg's word for it), you could copy the definition of `\include#1 ` from `latex.ltx` and just comment out the `\clearpage` definitions. Or define a command like `\xinclude` that properly groups the redefinition of `\clearpage`.

Comment: @jon I don't doubt egreg's statement, but he is not known for just statements, but also for good examples backing them up. Anyway, copying `\include#1` and `\@include#1` and removing `\clearpage` does not work, due to the way `\include` works. I added two more MWEs to the question.

Comment: @bers -- You are right. I did not realize how clever `\include` was before this evening. I am not in a position to comment on `newclude` however....